# display an image using fetch api when imageLink is provided - javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, fetch

I have been trying to get Image with the imageLink provided by backend server

```
getImage(imageLink) {
    let result;
    const url = `https://company.com/internal/document/download?ID=${imageLink}`;
    const proxyurl = 'https://cors-anywhere-proxy.herokuapp.com/';
    const req = new Request(proxyurl + url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'mode': 'no-cors',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      }
    });
     return fetch(req)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(function(response) {
          console.log('response', response);
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(response);
              return objectURL;
      });
  }
```

objectURL looks like blob:http://localhost:4200/f54ccb80-fd69-4e9e-8e89-2d2599ee3913 and when served to img.src , img src looks like this

```
<img _ngcontent-kab-c7="" class="img-fluid" width="60" src="[object Promise]">
```

How do you display an image with fetch api when the image link is given. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use the async pipe

```
<img class="img-fluid" width="60" [src]="objectURL | async">
```

[AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

> Unwraps a value from an asynchronous primitive.

Comment: ```<img _ngcontent-mnx-c7="" class="img-fluid" width="60" src="unsafe:blob:http://localhost:4200/04714efa-8e79-470d-997e-ed06150df40d">``` i get this when i bind src with src="objectURL | async"

Comment: Looks like you don't need URL.createObjectURL(response)

Comment: The response.blob() looks like ```Blob {size: 43849, type: "text/html"}``` and when i serve this to img without doing the URL.createObjectURL(response), it's src looks like below ```<img _ngcontent-fin-c7="" class="img-fluid" width="60" src="[object Blob]">```

Comment: Why are you downloading the image and converting it into a blob? Why not set it directly to the IMG tag?

Comment: the API provided is to download an image

Comment: This in combination with async should solve your problem